# How to use ToShortDateString() on nullable datetime column

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

How can I use `ToShortDateString()` method when a datetime column allow nulls?

I get the following error on this asp.net code `<%= Model.EndDate.ToShortDateString() %>` :

> 'System.Nullable' does not contain a definition for 'ToShortDateString' and no extension method 'ToShortDateString' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `Model.EndDate.Value.ToShortDateString()` ? Be sure to check `EndDate` is not null before accessing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The corret way to do that is like in this example:

```
<%=Model.EndDate.HasValue ? Model.EndDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty; %>
```

Nullable values always expose a property called "Value" that will contain data if is not null and another property, called "HasValue" that indicate if data is present or not.

Comment: I think it's a bad practice - use `string.Empty` instead of `null`

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov is just an example.

Answer (score 4):

In С# 6 you can write the follows:

```
<%= Model.EndDate?.ToShortDateString() %>
```

In earlier versions it is common to write it as

```
<%= Model.EndDate != null ? Model.EndDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : null %>
```

Comment: it has to be `<%= Model.EndDate?.ToShortDateString() %>`

Answer (score 0):

Nullable `DateTime` should be formatted like below;

```
<%= Model.EndDate.HasValue ? 
     Model.EndDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : 
     "Something"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below,

```
<%= Model.EndDate != null ? Model.EndDate.ToShortDateString() : "n/a" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this.

```
<%= Model.EndDate!= DBNull.Value ? Model.EndDate.ToShortDateString() : string.empty %>
```

Thanks